# what do emacs powerline items mean?

Tags: emacs, powerline

I finally got emacs powerline to work. It looks very nice. I can't seem to find *any* documentation on it though. What does `- 299 UU-:` and `All` mean in this screenshot

[image]

What else can it tell me? Are there any docs?

Comment: Maybe say where you looked for help. That might help someone who maintains powerline (or someone else) provide help in some of those places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--  
Indicates that the buffer has not been changed since the last save
**  
Indicates that the buffer has been changed since the last save
%%  
Indicates that the buffer is read-only (can't be changed)
```

More info here
https://kb.iu.edu/d/ablq
https://www.nada.kth.se/cgi-bin/info?(emacs)Mode%20Line